# Cascading dropdownlists ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cascadingdropdown

What I would like to be able to accomplish is:

Have the user select a Model first which would then display all Engines related to that Model. I have been trying to adapt code from related problems, but without success.

Here is the code from one of my attempts.

Any help would be appreciated.

**CarsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetEnginesByModelId(int ModelId)
    {
        EnginesRepository enginesRepository = new EnginesRepository();
        List<Engine> engines = enginesRepository.GetAll(cascadeInclude: true).SelectMany(e => e.EngineModels).Where(em => em.ModelId == ModelId).Select(em => em.ParentEngine).ToList();

        return Json(engines);
    }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
                Model:
                <select asp-items="@Model.Models" id="models">
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
                Engines:
                <select id="engines"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
        $("#models").html(items);
    });
    $("#models").change(function () {
        var modelId = $("#models").val();
        var url = "/Cars/GetEnginesByModelId";

        $.getJSON(url, { ModelId: modelId }, function (data) {
            var item = "";
            $("#engines").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, engine) {
                item += '<option value="' + engine.value + '">' + engine.text + '</option>'
            });
            $("#engines").html(item);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I managed to hit the controller and get the list of items but it displays "undefined". To show the items I use item.ToString() method. Here is the js and c# I used.
**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#models").on("change", function () {
            $list = $("#engines");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Cars/GetEnginesByModelId",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: $("#models").val() }, //id of the state which is used to extract cities
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    $list.empty();
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        $list.append('<option value="' + item["EngineId"] + '"> ' + item["ToString()"] + ' </option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong call the police");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="customDiv">
                Model:
                <select id="models" name="ModelId">
                    @foreach (var carModel in Model.Models)
                    {
                        <option value="@carModel.Id">@carModel.Name @carModel.Price$</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="customDiv">
                Engines:
                <select id="engines" name="EngineId">
                    @foreach (var engine in Model.Engines)
                    {
                        <option value="@engine.Id">@engine.ToString()</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is your controller getting hit in debug mode? Can you change the Url in the javascript to `var url = "/Cars/GetEnginesByModelId" + "/" + modelId;` and remove the `{ ModelId: modelId }`?

Comment: No, the controller is not getting hit. Changed the url but still not hitting the controller.
Usually when I pass parameter in the URL I do it like that: `/Cars/GetEnginesByModelId?ModelId=`
So I tried with `"?ModelId="` instead of  `"/"` but it still didn't work.

Comment: I have added local jquery in "wwwroot" just to make sure that it not the Google CDN that causes the problem. But still no results.

Here is the git of the project: https://github.com/Angel239200/AudiCarCustomization.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **JS** that worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#models").change(function () {
    $.get("/Cars/GetEnginesByModelId", { id: $("#models").val() }, function (data) {
        $("#engines").empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
            $("#engines").append("<option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
        });
    });
})
```

});